# How can I kill this annoying text bar at the bottom of every window?

Tags: unity

There is a bar at the bottom of every window I open.  It displays info on whatever the mouse is hovering on but tends to cover file names if I have the window maximized.  I tried searching, but I don't even know what to call this bar.  I have used Ubuntu and mint for over four years now, but can't remember this ever being an issue until recently.

Comment: That is the URL hover text in Chrome / Chromium.  It *should* only appear momentarily while hovering over a link.  And it should restrict itself to only the left or right half of the browser window, so as not to overlap what is under your mouse.  It should only expand to full size like this when you hover over a very long URL and keep hovering over it for a long time.  Can you confirm that this isn't what's happening for you?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

From my research, it appears you can't in Chrome:

- http://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/2cxyeq/how_do_i_turn_off_the_status_bar_the_little_bar/
- https://superuser.com/questions/239202/turn-off-the-link-hover-statusbar-in-google-chrome
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/FtD7qjochgw
- [https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=turn+off+status+bar+chrome&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=turn%20off%20status%20bar%20chrome&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

I think Firefox has an option to turn it off.

Comment: it will actually pop up in my file browser as well.  It's really annoying while organizing files as it tends to block the bottom row's file name.  Here is another picture of an open file browser window. ![http://imageshack.com/a/img537/9903/UXEx6a.png]